# If Windows XP has Virtual PC 2007 (free) and Windows 7 has Windows Virtual PC (free), what about for Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

Windows XP has a free downloadable Virtual PC 2007 form Microsoft's website.

And Windows 7 has Windows Virtual PC.

(Are they supposed to work the same on a .vhd file?)

What about Vista?  I ran Virtual PC 2007 on Vista and it said this program is not officially supported on Vista and I ran it anyway.  Is that fine?  Is there another program to run for Vista? (maybe VirtualBox? or any MS solution?)  Is it fine to run VPC 2007 as it is, or better to set some compatibility mode option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely run Virtual PC 2007 on Vista, it's not a problem; just check [this](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/virtual-pc-2007.aspx) link for more information. There are also quite a few alternatives to it: [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (free), [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) (paid) or [Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) (free), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/eu/products/desktop/pd4wl/) (paid).

Answer (score 4):

You can run Virtual PC 2007 on Vista. When Microsoft says it's not "officially supported", it usually means that they won't provide official tech support.

VirtualBox may be a better choice for you since it is actively developed and supported by Sun. It works fine on Vista & Windows 7. Sun releases a new build every month or two at this point.